# Ant task to refresh IvyDE Eclipse libraries

Tags: eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I use Ivy for dependency management with the IvyDE Eclipse plugin and I have dependent libraries that change quite frequently and Eclipse doesn't seem to refresh the libraries when I refresh the workspace.

```
<eclipse.refreshLocal depth="*" resource="/" />
```

Is there a way to get eclipse to refresh the Ivy libraries using an ant task, or refresh them upon a workspace refresh?

Comment: So the libraries change, but not the name or the versions of them?

Comment: I basically run a <ivy:resolve...> task as part of my script. It resolves the new versions of the dependent libraries, but the ivy.xml library doesn't refresh to display the new jars that just got resolved.

Comment: So you're using an Ant build, and not the standard Eclipse build mechanism? IvyDE has no knowledge of your build.xml file, and I don't know of any programmatic way to call IvyDE.

Comment: If you're not already calling your build file from Ant Builder, maybe try that and refresh the project when activating your build there?

Comment: Yes, ant for the build and ivy for dependency management. I would be satisfied if there was some setting in IvyDE that automatically refreshed the libraries when the project built, or changed, or something like that. But, I can't find such a setting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [touch](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) the ivy.xml.
This might trigger an update of ivy after a workspace refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can go in the Windows -> Preference -> on Eclipse Startup and change to Trigger Refresh

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Refresh or Resolve on the right-click menu for the "ivy.xml" Eclipse Library in the project?

Comment: I can, but I'd like for it to be seemless and part of the ant script. I don't want another manual step, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [oers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778891/1930619) and [Pat B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530966/1930619) above, you would need to go to Window > Preferences > Ivy, and change the following preferences:

- Set "On Eclipse startup" to "Trigger resolve", and
- Set "On Ivy File Change" to "Trigger resolve"

These should do the trick, especially in combination with the "touch" suggestion that oers made in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778891/1930619).

[image]